# How to enable while 1 loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I am planning to make a BMI calculation in which this program will prompt the user to enter new inputs repetitively as long as both inputs are positive. In this case, my input is weight and height. I have applied `while` loop in my code. However, when I enter two positive inputs and after the BMI calculation has been performed, the process ends and exits. May I know which line did I code wrongly?

```
while 1

if (Weight > 0 && Height > 0)
Weight = input('Please Enter Your Weight In kg: ');
Height = input('Please Enter Your Height In m : ');
    
    BMI = Weight/(Height^2);

    if (BMI<=18.5)
    disp(['Health condition: THIN. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
    

    elseif (BMI>=18.6) && (BMI<=24.9)
    disp(['Health condition: HEALTHY. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
    

    elseif (BMI<=25) && (BMI<=29.9)
    disp(['Health condition: OVERWEIGHT. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
    

    else (BMI>=30)
    disp(['Health condition: OBESE. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
    
    end
 
        break
    end
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't call the if statement if weight and height conditions have not been defined yet with the prompt. So you should call `input()` before `if`:

```
Weight = input('Please Enter Your Weight In kg: ');
Height = input('Please Enter Your Height In m : ');
if (Weight > 0 && Height > 0)
```

Now, you can run your code. Your problem is the`break`. This is how you defined your code:

```
while loop 1 (forever)
    prompt asking for weight and height
    if weight & height > 0 (positive)
        (...some other calculations and if)
    break
```

If you check this pseudo-code, you are telling your code that if weight and height are positive, break the while loop, therefore it stops. The right condition should be:

```
if weight & height > 0 (positive)
    run...
else (not positive)
    break
```

This is your code fixed:

```
while 1

    Weight = input('Please Enter Your Weight In kg: ');
    Height = input('Please Enter Your Height In m : ');
    if (Weight > 0 && Height > 0)
        
        BMI = Weight/(Height^2);
    
        if (BMI<=18.5)
        disp(['Health condition: THIN. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
        
    
        elseif (BMI>=18.6) && (BMI<=24.9)
        disp(['Health condition: HEALTHY. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
        
    
        elseif (BMI<=25) && (BMI<=29.9)
        disp(['Health condition: OVERWEIGHT. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
        
    
        else (BMI>=30)
        disp(['Health condition: OBESE. Your BMI is ', num2str(BMI)]);
        
        end
        
    else
        break
    end
end
```

Try to take always care of the identation. Your first `if` and its final `end` wasn't equally.